# How to you add context to be passed along with agent.run in ReAct LangChain framework

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I've previously built a pdf searching tool in LangChain which uses the
`chain.run(input_documents=, question=)` syntax to ask the model questions along with context from that pdf.
I want to integrate this with the agents provided by langchain.
I am using the syntax `agent.run('Question')`

I am not able to find links to integrate the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

How do solve it?

Did you try using the result of the chain as a text input for the agent? The syntax should looks like:

`agent_input = chain.run(input_documents=, question=)\n agent(agent_input+"question")`